# How to read datetime back from sqlite as a datetime instead of string in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, sqlite

I'm using the sqlite3 module in Python 2.6.4 to store a datetime in a SQLite database. Inserting it is very easy, because sqlite automatically converts the date to a string. The problem is, when reading it it comes back as a string, but I need to reconstruct the original datetime object. How do I do this?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

If you declare your column with a type of timestamp, you're in clover:

```
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
>>> c = db.cursor()
>>> c.execute('create table foo (bar integer, baz timestamp)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x40fc50>
>>> c.execute('insert into foo values(?, ?)', (23, datetime.datetime.now()))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x40fc50>
>>> c.execute('select * from foo')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x40fc50>
>>> c.fetchall()
[(23, datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 1, 19, 31, 1, 40113))]
```

See? both int (for a column declared integer) and datetime (for a column declared timestamp) survive the round-trip with the type intact.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, it works! I'm surprised by this, because there is no mention of the TIMESTAMP type at all on http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @Evgeny, see http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#default-adapters-and-converters -- it's not documented at sqlite.org because it's actually implemented in the Python layer, not in sqlite itself!

Comment: I just find out it is the __detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES__ parameter of the connect function that makes fetchall returns a datetime. If you omit it you will have a unicode object.

Comment: Seems like this fails for timezone aware values like `u'2012-01-01 18:35:24.617954-02:00'`

Comment: I had a tangential question on this issue, but I've created a new one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840382/sqlite-python-retrieve-current-timestamp-as-datetime-object. Is the issue related? It sounds like it MIGHT be.

Comment: @AlexMartelli the datetime value returns via SQLITE is being considered as a Tuple when I try to use strftime function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the rationale for TIMESTAMP working but not DATETIME?

Comment: It's not reliable ... File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 67, in convert_timestamp
    datepart, timepart = val.split(b" ")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: I'm using python 3.8 and declared my variable as DATE. After using `detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES`, sqlite3 returns a datetime.date object. Otherwise, it returns a string.

Answer (score 31):

It turns out that sqlite3 can do this and it's even [documented](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#module-functions-and-constants), kind of - but it's pretty easy to miss or misunderstand.

What I had to do is:

- Pass the **sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES** option in the .connect() call, eg.

> ```
> conn = sqlite3.connect(dbFilePath, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
> ```

- Put the type I wanted into the query - and for datetime, it's not actually "datetime", but "timestamp":

  ```
  sql = 'SELECT jobid, startedTime as "[timestamp]" FROM job'

  cursor = conn.cursor()
  try:
      cursor.execute(sql)
      return cursor.fetchall()
  finally:
      cursor.close()
  ```

If I pass in "datetime" instead it's silently ignored and I still get a string back. Same if I omit the quotes.

Comment: note that it's definitely `"[timestamp]"`, `[timestamp]` is silently ignored, and `.fetchone` also won't convert the types. What an odd library.

Comment: It seemed what really count is the double quote characters, neither the alias you explicitly specified nor the `as` keyword

Comment: I have now filed https://bugs.python.org/issue35145 'sqlite3: "select *" should autoconvert datetime fields'.

Comment: ^bug issue has been migrated here: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/79326

Comment: do note here that in 3.12 https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90016 that datetime converters are deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Note: In Python3, I had to change the SQL to something like:

`SELECT jobid, startedTime as "st [timestamp]" FROM job`

(I had to explicitly name the column.)

Comment: As @AdamBaxter said, what really count is the double quote characters, neither the alias you explicitly specified nor the `as` keyword. e.g., this works fine: `SELECT jobid, startedTime "[timestamp]" FROM job`