# Aggregating date column breaks PARSE_DECLTYPES

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an SQLite database in which I have declared certain columns type DATE (allowable but, of course, ignored by SQLite as it does not have a DATE type).  I am storing my dates as SQLite date strings.

When connecting from Python, I pass `detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES` to the connection.  This allows the sqlite library to correctly determine which columns contain dates and it correctly provides me with a `date` object, not a string when I read from these columns.

However, if I *aggregate* a date column, I get back a string, not a date:

```
 SELECT MIN(ReportDate) FROM PatientReports WHERE PatientID = ?;
```

produces a string, not a date value.  Interestingly this SQL:

```
 SELECT ReportDate FROM PatientReports WHERE PatientID = ? ORDER BY ReportDate DESC LIMIT 1;
```

correctly produces a date value (and this is the work-around I am using).

Question: Is there some way I can modify either the first SQL statement or my database definition to allow Python to preserve the implied date conversion?

Comment: Guess already answered
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429788/reading-back-a-datetime-in-sqlite3

Comment: Oops - duplicate indeed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PARSE_DECLTYPES` works only when you are using a column value *directly*; any processing done on it, such as passing it through a function, or doing arithmetic, or simply `+ReportDate`, will lose the declared type information.

This means that `PARSE_DECLTYPES` is not very useful in practice.

If you really want to use Python's type converters, you should enable [`PARSE_COLNAMES`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES) and add the type to the column name when needed:

```sql
SELECT MIN(ReportDate) AS "ReportDate [date]" FROM ...
```