# sqlite - python Retrieve CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, sqlite, timestamp

I'm using a local sqlite database to do offline processing of metadata in my application and the metadata includes timestamps.

I have a table declared as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tbl_dbsync_meta (
             maindb_last_checked TIMESTAMP,
             global_scores_last_checked TIMESTAMP,
             localscores_syncup_last_checked TIMESTAMP)
```

Now, at one point I retrieve the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` from sqlite along with all the other timestamps above, so as to - naturally - figure out the differences in time between now and all these other timestamps.

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as this_time, * FROM tbl_dbsync_meta
```

Now the problem is, that all the other fields are retrieved correctly as "datetime" objects in Python. However `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is returned as a string.

I tried casting `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP), * FROM tbl_dbsync_meta
```

But now it's being returned as an INTEGER, and all that's returned is the year (2012).

An easy way for me to work around this is to just directly `SELECT` the time-diffs from sqlite itself, instead of retrieving them into python and then playing around. Another option is for me to use the string returned by `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, convert it in Python to a "datetime" and use that.

However I need to understand WHAT the difference between `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (cast or otherwise) and the other `TIMESTAMP` fields is. It just seems wrong that this doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

P.S: Please note, I never store Python datettime objects directly into SQLite. Anytime I need to update this table, I just `SET global_scores_last_checked = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I only retrieve the dates from SQLite into Python out of necessity.

Comment: I have <code>detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES</code> set btw

Comment: This seems to be an issue with 'functions' in general. I tried this - SELECT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - maindb_last_checked) FROM tbl_dbsync_meta. And this returned me a unicode string too, rather than a DATETIME object. Whereas if I select just an existing TIMESTAMP field - such as "maindb_last_checked" - it returns a datetime object.......Is that the issue?

Comment: How did you store the Python `datetime` objects into the timestamp columns? How are they converted? Please post some Python code, too.

Comment: @Tichodroma, that's a great question. I'm not actually storing Python datetime objects ever directly into sqlite. All I ever do is update these timestamps with a "UPDATE tbl_dbsync_meta SET global_scores_last_checked = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". So the date-time values are all internal to SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `PARSE_COLNAMES` when connecting:

`sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)`

Then the following will work:

`select current_timestamp as 'ts [timestamp]'`

This will return `"2012-08-07 13:20:42" (<type 'datetime.datetime'>)`.

CAST does not work (most probably a bug) and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP does not return a datetime type indeed, which might be a bug, or a feature (remember, Sqlite has no notion of date/time types, it stores them as TEXT/REAL/INTEGER).

Comment: This is (literally) years later, and I'm sorry I can't recall why I didn't respond to this answer at the time - couple of doubts. First, what would be the difference between "SET column_name = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" and then reading that column, versus "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"? Because I got a date-time object in the first case. Could this simply be a bug like you mentioned? Second question - my SQL syntax knowledge is rusty - in "ts [timestamp]" is "timestamp" supposed to indicate the datatype of the "virtual" "ts" column returned in the query?