# How can I export to sqlite (or another format) and retain the date datatype?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have a script that loads a CSV into a pandas dataframe, cleanses the resulting table (eg removes invalid values, formats dates as dates, etc) and saves the output to a local sqlite .db file.

I then have other scripts that open that database file and perform other operations on it.

My problem is that Sqlite3 doesn't have an explicit date format: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
This means that operations on dates fail, e.g.:

```
df_read['Months since mydate 2'] = (  pd.to_datetime('15-03-2019') - df_read['mydate'] )
```

returns

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str'

**How can I export my dataframe in a way which keeps track of all the data types, including dates?**

I have thought of the following:

- Export to another format, but what format? A proper SQL Server would be great, but I don't have access to any in this case. I'd need a format which EXPLICITLY declares the data type of each column, so CSV is not an option.
- Having a small function which reconverts the columns to dates, after reading them from SQL lite. But this would mean I'd have to manually keep track of what the column dates are - it would be cumbersome and slow on large datasets.
- Having another table in the SQL lite database which keeps track of which columns are dates, and what format they are in (e.g. %Y-%m-%d); this can help with the reconversion into dates, but it still feels very cumbersome, clunky and very un-pythonic.

Here is a quick example of what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
num=int(10e3)
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['month'] = np.random.randint(1,13,num)
df['year'] = np.random.randint(2000,2005,num)
df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'] * 10000 + df['month']* 100 + df['month'], format ='%Y%m%d' )
df.iloc[20:30,2]=np.nan

#this works
df['Months since mydate'] = (  pd.to_datetime('15-03-2019') - df['mydate'] )

conn=sqlite3.connect("test_sqllite_dates.db")
df.to_sql('mydates',conn, if_exists='replace')
conn.close()

conn2=sqlite3.connect("test_sqllite_dates.db")

df_read=pd.read_sql('select * from mydates',conn2 )
# this doesn't work
df_read['Months since mydate 2'] = (  pd.to_datetime('15-03-2019') - df_read['mydate'] )
conn2.close()

print(df.dtypes)
print(df_read.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here (w/ sqlite writing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933720/how-do-i-insert-datetime-value-into-a-sqlite-database), [here (reading back from sqlite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829872/how-to-read-datetime-back-from-sqlite-as-a-datetime-instead-of-string-in-python),  the solution could be by creating the column type in sqlite as a datetime, so that when reading back, python will convert automatically to the `datetime` type.

Mind that, when you are connecting to the database, you need to give the parameter **detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES**

Comment: Thank you - this works! However, I must say I haven't fully understood what's going on. Can you help me clarify? The docs say SQL lite does NOT have a datetime format. So how can detect_types make pandas understand the column is a date? I even changed the column name to 'banana' and it still works. SQL lite does not have a date format but stores some metadata that helps other programs interpret that column as a date?

Comment: sorry, I was OTK. Dates are usually stored in [ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), so when you store them in this standard format, you can also retrieve them, even if it's not a field of type date, but just a string one.

Like if I write *+45 2548655* (random number), no one said it's a phone, but that's the standard format to write phone numbers