# sqlite3 returns byte string for datetime

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime

I have a sqlite3 database:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

batch_size = 10

con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cur = con.cursor()

table = """CREATE TABLE my_table(DateCreated DATETIME);"""
cur.execute(table)

DateCreated = [datetime(2020, 12, 1, 1, 1)] * batch_size
x = list(pd.DataFrame({'DateCreated':DateCreated}).to_records(index=False))

query = """INSERT INTO my_table (DateCreated) values (?);"""

cur.executemany(query, x)
```

When I want to retrieve my datetimes, sqlite3 returns a byte string instead of a datetime object:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table;")
cur.fetchone()
```

```
>> (b'\x00\xf8\xea\x08\xf4qL\x16',)
```

What am I doing wrong? I have checked [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829872/how-to-read-datetime-back-from-sqlite-as-a-datetime-instead-of-string-in-python) but it is not really applicable for my problem. I also tried changing the sqlite datatype from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP, but received `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`. I am using Python 3.8.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two incorrectnesses in your snippet: The correct datatype for sqlite3 column is `timestamp`, not `datetime`. Sqlite3 is, well, peculiar, it will just accept anything and store everything internally as strings - it is the Python driver that will treat the column type "timestamp" differently, and able to accept and retrieve datetime objects directly.

That said, the "df.to_record" call does not help either, as it retrieves the pandas datetimes as strings. The correct thing is to retrieve each pandas cell value and call `.to_pydatetime()` on it.

So, if you need to convert from another, not given in the example, dataframe to sqlite, this sort of code works:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

batch_size = 10

con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cur = con.cursor()

table = """CREATE TABLE my_table(DateCreated timestamp)"""
cur.execute(table)

DateCreated = [datetime(2020, 12, 1, 1, 1)] * batch_size
x = [(rec.to_pydatetime(),)  for rec in  pd.DataFrame({'DateCreated':DateCreated})["DateCreated"]]

query = """INSERT INTO my_table (DateCreated) values (?)"""
cur.executemany(query, x)
```

the way I wrote the `x =` expression above will allow you to select the desired columns from your dataframe, and call `.to_pydatetime()` only in the desired fields.

If your dataframe have 5 other colimns, and datetime is on the 3rd [index 2], this works:

```
x = [(*rec[0:2], rec[2].to_pydatetime(), *rec[3:])  for _, rec in df.iterrows()]
```

And, if you are not converting things from a pandas workflow at all, there is no need to meddle with it, just create datetime objects as tuples and insert them:

```
x = [(datetime.now(),) for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies with my use of pandas' `.to_record()` method. If I cut that step out and supply a list of *tuples* instead of a list of *numpy records*, then the database returns datetimes properly.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

batch_size = 10

con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cur = con.cursor()

table = """CREATE TABLE my_table(DateCreated DATETIME);"""
cur.execute(table)

DateCreated = [(datetime(2020, 12, 1, 1, 1),)] * batch_size

query = """INSERT INTO my_table (DateCreated) values (?);"""

cur.executemany(query, DateCreated)

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table;")

cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: this still returns the resutls as strings, not Python datetime objects: the OP got the wrong column type for sqlite - should be "timestamp"  .
Besides, I think in the example given the use of Pandas is redundant, but in the OP usecase it might be needed - so, we have to extract the information from the dataframe as datetime objects.

Comment: Good catch. Your answer is more thorough than my own, too. Thanks!